# How to check service success or error in controller in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, perl

I have a function in controller which calls a service function. This is the code for both.

Controller

```
 $scope.AddNewProduct = function (NewProduct)  {

    var newProduct = {};

    newProduct.ProductID = NewProduct.id;
    newProduct.ProductName = NewProduct.name;
    newProduct.ProductImagePath = NewProduct.imagepath;
    newProduct.SubCategoryID = NewProduct.subcategory.id;
    newProduct.SubCategoryName = NewProduct.subcategory.name;
    newProduct.BrandID = NewProduct.brand.id;
    newProduct.BrandName = NewProduct.brand.name;
    newProduct.Variants = [];

    ProductService.AddNewProduct(newProduct);
    $scope.NewProduct = {};
    $scope.NewProduct.id = parseInt($scope.Products[0].ProductID) + 1;

};
```

Service

```
ProductService.AddNewProduct = function(NewProduct)  {

    productList.unshift(NewProduct);
    var req = {
        url: "cgi-bin/AddNewProduct.pl",
        method: 'GET',
        params: {ProductID: NewProduct.ProductID, ProductName: NewProduct.ProductName, ProductImagePath: NewProduct.ProductImagePath, BrandID: NewProduct.BrandID, SubCategoryID: NewProduct.SubCategoryID}
        //params: { NewProduct: ProductData }
    };

    $http(req).success(function()
    {
        alert ('New Product Added!');
    })
    .error(function()
    {
        alert ('New Product Add Error!');
    });

}
```

Perl Script for adding the product.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use cPanelUserConfig;

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI;
use CGI::Cookie;
use CGI::Session qw();
use JSON;

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

my $CFG = do "config.pl";
my $db_handle = DBI->connect ("DBI:mysql:$CFG->{database}", $CFG->{user}, $CFG->{password} ) or die "Couldn't connect to database: $DBI::errstr\n";

my $cgi = CGI->new();
#my $DecodedData = decode_json($cgi->param("NewProduct"));

my $product_id = $cgi->param('ProductID');
my $product_name = $cgi->param('ProductName');
my $product_description = 'DESC';
my $image_path = $cgi->param('ProductImagePath');
my $brand_id = $cgi->param('BrandID');
my $subcatty_id = $cgi->param('SubCategoryID');

my $sql_query = "insert into table_products values ($product_id, '$product_name', '$product_description', '$image_path', '$brand_id', 1)";
my $statement = $db_handle->prepare ($sql_query) or die "Couldn't prepare query '$sql_query': $DBI::errstr\n";  
$statement->execute() or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";  

$sql_query = "insert into table_product_categories values ($product_id, '$subcatty_id')";
my $statement = $db_handle->prepare ($sql_query) or die "Couldn't prepare query '$sql_query': $DBI::errstr\n";  
$statement->execute() or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";  

$db_handle->disconnect;
```

I have the following issues with the code.

1. Sometimes products is not getting added into DB, but in service i am seeing alert ('New Product Added!'); why is that so? Why it is not going to alert ('New Product Add Error!');
2. How to check for success or error in controller instead of service?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

1. May be your returning http status code `200` after the request when its not inserting to the database, If the data is not insert correctly, you need to return a `$http` error.
2. you can return the `$http` promise from the service as below,

   ```
   ProductService.AddNewProduct = function(NewProduct)  {

       productList.unshift(NewProduct);
       var req = {
             url: "cgi-bin/AddNewProduct.pl",
             method: 'GET',
             params: {ProductID: NewProduct.ProductID, ProductName: NewProduct.ProductName, ProductImagePath: NewProduct.ProductImagePath, BrandID: NewProduct.BrandID, SubCategoryID: NewProduct.SubCategoryID}
             //params: { NewProduct: ProductData }
        }; 

        return $http(req); 

   }
   ```

in controller,

```
ProductService.AddNewProduct(newProduct).then(function(data) {

     // success

}, function(data) {

     // error

});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But i think i am not returning code 200. I have pasted the script code code. There i am using die statement if not success.

Comment: put a `console.log(data);` inside the two callback functions and check the responses.

Answer (score 0):

[`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is able to utilize the response data:

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Make your API `cgi-bin/AddNewProduct.pl` to return success/error/status data. `console.log` to see what it returns, so that you can debug.